# $\text{Determinant}=(\sum \text{Determinant})^2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, partitions

Denote by $\delta_{n-1}=(n-1,n-2,\dots,1,0,0,\dots)$ the staircase partition and the embedded partition
$\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)\subset\delta_{n-1}$.

> **QUESTION 1.** Is this true?
>   $$\det\left[\binom{i+j-1}{2j-i-1}+\binom{i+j-2}{2j-i-2}\right]_{i,j=1}^n=
> \left(\sum_{\lambda\,\subset\,\delta_{n-1}}
> \det\left[\binom{n-i}{\lambda_j-j+i}\right]_{i,j=1}^n\right)^2.$$

A diagonal version of this (relative to the RHS) takes the form:

> **QUESTION 2.** Is this true?
>   $$\det\left[\binom{i+j-2}{2j-i-1}\right]_{i,j=1}^n=
> \sum_{\lambda\,\subset\,\delta_{n-1}}
> \left(\det\left[\binom{n-i}{\lambda_j-j+i}\right]_{i,j=1}^n\right)^2.$$

Comment: Dat title......

Comment: See Section 3.2 (equation 3.10) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0611012.pdf

Comment: This is not the same as what I posted.

Comment: Never said it was the `same'; perhaps equivalent. Both your determinants are really n-1 x n-1 determinants. The sum of determinants appearing in the RHS of your question refines the TSSCPP count. Question 2 is essentially asking for a demonstration of the fact that the set of certain pairs of TSSCPPs (inside a 2n x 2n x 2n box) is equi-numerous with the set of CSTCPPs inside the same box. Sage says that is what the LHS of question 2 counts. So the LHS better be some determinant obtained by an NILP description of CSTCPPs. All of what I said is present in Di Francesco's paper.